# Do I need a UK visa even for a day?

Tags: visas

I am traveling from India to Prague with a Schengen visa. On my way back, I have a long transit (34 hours) at London. I picked this as I got the best rates. Can I step out of the airport & take in a couple of sites without a UK visa? appreciate your help!

Comment: Also, it may be the case that for a layover >24 hours, you need a "proper" visa anyway. Not sure if that is the case, but you should definitely check.

Comment: If your nationality is such that you need a visa to enter the UK, then you need a visa _to get in_, no matter how long or short your stay will be. There is a "transit-without-visa" scheme for landside transits, but it comes with additional conditions (see the linked question) that it is not clear from your question that you fulfill.

Comment: @DCTLib it depends on the time of the departureflight, not the duration if the stay. The flight must be scheduled to leave by 23:59 of the day following arrival. MeshNad, are you arriving before 2 p.m.?